# Pandas Period with custom duration

Tags: python, pandas, period

Reading the docs of the pandas `Period` objects leaves me confused as to whether it is somehow possible to create a custom Period. By custom I mean a Period that does not follow a certain frequency `dtype` but where each Period in a `PeriodIndex` represents a start timestamp and an end timestamp, that is manually defined.

To illustrate:

Lets say I have **n** time intervals **t**, where the beginning and end of each interval are samples from a discrete uniformly distributed random variable with the constraint that the **beginning < end**.

The result would somewhat look like this:

```
[(ts_start0, ts_end0), (ts_start1, ts_end1), (ts_start2, ts_end2))]
```

Is there any way to encode such "random" intervals/ timespans/ periods with Pandas `Period` or something similar?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you can use [IntervalIndex](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.IntervalIndex.html):

```
In [18]: pd.IntervalIndex([pd.Interval(1,3), pd.Interval(4, 11), pd.Interval(13, 28)])
Out[18]:
IntervalIndex([(1, 3], (4, 11], (13, 28]]
              closed='right',
              dtype='interval[int64]')
```

using timestamps:

```
In [25]: pd.IntervalIndex([
    ...:   pd.Interval(pd.to_datetime('2018-01-01'), pd.to_datetime('2018-01-13')),
    ...:   pd.Interval(pd.to_datetime('2018-03-08'), pd.to_datetime('2018-04-29')),
    ...:   pd.Interval(pd.to_datetime('2018-05-03'), pd.to_datetime('2018-07-22'))
    ...: ])
    ...:
Out[25]:
IntervalIndex([(2018-01-01, 2018-01-13], (2018-03-08, 2018-04-29], (2018-05-03, 2018-07-22]]
              closed='right',
              dtype='interval[datetime64[ns]]')
```

---

**UPDATE:** we can use `pd.IntervalIndex.from_tuples()` constructor:

```
In [16]: pd.IntervalIndex.from_tuples([(1,3), (4, 11), (13, 28)], closed='right')
Out[16]:
IntervalIndex([(1, 3], (4, 11], (13, 28]]
              closed='right',
              dtype='interval[int64]')
```